# Preview image not appearing when Facebook 'Share' function on FB Business Page

Tags: wordpress, facebook

I'm running a custom Wordpress theme (Bettermag), and I'm running into a problem.

I created a Facebook Business Page for [my blog](http://joyceofcooking.com).  But every time I share a link to my blog post I don't get a preview image!  It's weird, because one (and only one) of my shares worked just fine.  But since then all of my Shared links aren't assigned a preview image.  [Here's a side-by-side screenshot](http://imgur.com/MtIeG71).

I've tried the following with no success:

- Debugging using Facebook's Debug tool
- Removed the 'http://' and 'www.' in front of the link as well as the '/' at the end of the link.
- Tried all of the fixes in WordPress.org's troubleshooting page.  I'd link it, but don't yet have enough reputation to post more than 2 links
- Waited more than 24 hours for Facebook to scrape the page
- Cleared my browser's cache and cookies
- Tried sharing the link using Chrome, then Firefox.

Any solutions?

Comment: the problem is that your posts don't have any default image for that as per your page source. 
Check this : view-source:http://joyceofcooking.com/marben-toronto/
Line: 56

Comment: Hi Rohit.  I actually found out what the problem was.  It looks like Facebook had trouble scraping my site for images.  So, what I had to do with download the Wordpress plugin 'All In One SEO Pack', and set a image in the plugin's 'Social Settings' section.  Then, I had to use Facebook's Debug Tool, and share the link from the link provided by FB.

It's too bad that a 3rd party plug-in was necessary to get the preview image to show properly, but it seems to be working, now.